# How to enable a custom shipping method for API in Magento 2?

Tags: custom-options, shipping-methods, admin-panel, rest-api, magento2.2.6

We have created a custom shipping method in magento2, It's being added to the JSON response when we fetch the order data as well.

But we are not able to append it in post request JSON of order creation as a new method and carrier code respectively.

Can anyone suggest how can we add it to API?